# How to do an else (default) in match-case?

Tags: python, python-3.10, structural-pattern-matching

[Python recently has released match-case in version 3.10](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.10.html#pep-634-structural-pattern-matching). The question is how can we do a default case in Python? I can do `if/elif` but don't know how to do else. Below is the code:

```
x = "hello"
match x:
    case "hi":
        print(x)
    case "hey":
        print(x)
    default:
        print("not matched")
```

I added this `default` myself. I want to know the method to do this in Python.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You can define a default case in Python. For this [you use a *wild card* (`_`)](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0635/#id3). The following code demonstrates it:

```py
x = "hello"
match x:
    case "hi":
        print(x)
    case "hey":
        print(x)
    case _:
        print("not matched")
```

Answer (score 3):

```py
match subject:
    case <pattern_1>:
        <action_1>
    case <pattern_2>:
        <action_2>
    case <pattern_3>:
        <action_3>
    case _:
        <action_wildcard>
```

cf: https://docs.python.org/3.10/whatsnew/3.10.html#syntax-and-operations

Answer (score 1):

```
for thing in [[1,2],[2,11],[12,14,13],[10],[10,20,30,40,50]]:
match thing:
    case [x]:
        print(f"single value: {x}")
    case [x,y]:
        print(f"two values: {x} and {y}")
    case [x,y,z]:
        print(f"three values: {x}, {y} and {z}")       
    case _: # change this in default 
        print("too many values")
```

If you want to read and get more understanding: https://towardsdatascience.com/pattern-matching-in-python-3-10-6124ff2079f0

Answer (score 0):

```
def option_a():
    print('A')
    
def option_b():
    print('B')

def option_c():
    print('C')

def option_d():
    print('D')
    
def by_default():
    print('Default choice')

_switch_dict = {0:option_a, 1:option_b, 2:option_c, 3:option_d, 4:option_b, 5:option_c}

def switch(choice):
    selected_option = _switch_dict.get(choice, by_default)
    selected_option()

switch(12)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).