# azura databricks custom function not working (python)

Tags: python, match, databricks

In databricks/python I am trying to create a custom function and I'm receiving an error.

here is the function I am trying to create:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, substr
def CreateBloombergSymbol(pctym):
    
    digitMonth = pctym[6:2:1]

    match digitMonth:
        case "01":
            charMonth = "F"
        case "02":
            charMonth = "G"    
        case "03":
            charMonth = "H"  
        case "04":
            charMonth = "J"  
        case "05":
            charMonth = "K"  
        case "06":
            charMonth = "M"  
        case "07":
            charMonth = "N"  
        case "08":
            charMonth = "Q"  
        case "09":
            charMonth = "U"  
        case "10":
            charMonth = "V" 
        case "11":
            charMonth = "X" 
        case "12":
            charMonth = "Z"                            
    return charMonth
```

then I save it to variable, and lastly is how I am trying to implement it.

```
varMyBloombergFunction = spark.udf.register("CreateBloombergSymbol", CreateBloombergSymbol)

from pyspark.sql.functions import col

dfPos.select(
    col('*'),
    varMyBloombergFunction(col('pctym')).alias('mynewcolFuncBB')
).display()
```

this is the error I am receiving, any idea what I am doing wrong?

```
nboundLocalError: local variable 'charMonth' referenced before assignmen
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UnboundLocalError` is getting raised since your match statement is not matching any of your cases.

Either try print to console what values/types of objects are passed from `digitMonth` to the match statement in `CreateBloombergSymbol` and adjust to match for those or set a [default case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68804209/how-to-do-an-else-default-in-match-case) like so:

```
...
case "12":
    charMonth = "z"
case _:
    charMonth = "foo" # Whatever you want your default to be.
...
```

*Also in general its better to use a dict/[defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)/if-else statement for this kind of operation as match statements are meant for structural pattern matching instead.*

For example:

```
from collections import defaultdict

match_dict = defaultdict(lambda: "foo",  # What you want your default to be.
  {
  "01": "F",
  "02": "G",
  "03": "H",
  # ...
  })

charMonth = match_dict[digitMonth]
```

Or

```
match_dict = {
  "01": "F",
  "02": "G",
  "03": "H",
  # ...
  }

charMonth = match_dict.get(digitMonth, "foo")  # Your default is "foo"
```

Comment: if its better I can def use dict/default but not sure what that is.  do you have an example?

Comment: and how to I print to console... I added print(charMonth) but since I put it in the function I dont know where I would see results

Comment: Made an edit to show you an example how to replace the match statement with a default(dict).

Comment: If you are printing the `charMonth` variable it would cause an UnboundLocalError again, you should check your `digitMonth` instead as that will tell you what to match for.

Comment: thank you.  when I put a print(digitMonth), where would it get printed to?  I can't see the results anywhere.  Is it because I put the print inside the function?

Comment: Its either gonna pop up just before the `UnboundLocalError` and its associated Traceback in your console or databricks logs. If that doesn't work and the udf function is blocking the print statement, you can raise an exception from the udf function with the data from the print statement as the message instead.